# Ubuntu server pingable but stuck at startup waiting for network to be configured

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 22.04, ping

When starting up a fresh install of the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Server, I see it is waiting for a long time at the line below before finishing up the startup.

```
A start job is running for Wait for...e Configured (1min 31s / no limit)
```

During this time, the machine can be pinged, but OpenSSH service has not started yet.

Why is it waiting for the network to be configured, when it is already pingable? Is there a fix for this?